# У меня почему то моргает то первый то второй персонаж для игры пинг понг, пожалуйста помогите :)

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 300))

pygame.display.set_caption("PingToPong")

#Var's

POSX = 0
POSY = 50
WIDTH = 40
HEIGHT = 80
SPEED = 5

BPOSX = 560
BWIDTH = 40
BGHEIGHT = 80
BPOSY = 0

#Main loop start

RUN = True
while RUN:

    #Main loop end

    #Game body start
    
    pygame.time.delay(1)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            RUN = False

    win.fill((0,0,0))

    #Game body end
            
    #Player start

    
    
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_UP] and POSY > 0:
        POSY -= SPEED
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and POSY < 220:
        POSY += SPEED
    
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255,255,255), (BPOSX, BPOSY, WIDTH, HEIGHT))
    pygame.display.update()



    

    #Player end

    #Bot start

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and BPOSY > 0:
        BPOSY -= SPEED
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and BPOSY < 220:
        BPOSY += SPEED

    
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255,255,255), (POSX, POSY, WIDTH, HEIGHT))
    pygame.display.update()
    
    #Bot end
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Переменные с буквой В в начале отвечают за второго персонажа, а без буквы В за первого первый у меня моргает

Comment: если оставить только одно обновление экрана в цикле, не поможет ?